# Does word order make a difference here?

Tags: nouns, word-order

I was writing an essay and I wrote this particular sentence:

"No bought views"

then, while checking for grammatical errors, I thought that this sentence should be correct this way:

"No views bought"

But I couldn't explain myself, as a non-native English speaker, why the first sentence isn't correct, or if it is correct in some colloquial way.

Comment: Hello, Crocco. Neither is a sentence (unless _No_ is a person). As fragments, the second is more likely to be used. You might like to visit our sister site, ELL, where the more basic questions learners understandably have are more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your fragments actually mean different things. In compressing the full sentence, word order becomes important.

Adjectives are rarely post-positive (positioned after the noun) in English. Because of this feature, it's possible to reason that in the first case, *bought* functions as an adjective; in the second, it's not a simple adjective and is therefore indicative of a headline style where main verbs are omitted.

- No bought views

  This uses *bought* as a simple adjective describing *views*. The fragment indicates that there are no views which have been bought.
- No views bought

  Here, *bought* functions as a participle, but it's not the main verb; that has been omitted. The full sentence would be something like "No views will be bought".

Both fragments are "correct" — inasmuch as the severe compression allows that — but the first will not be correct if the intended meaning is that of the second (and vice-versa).